# Eloquent toArray doesn't work for sub query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When I have a sub query, can't get Laravel DB query results as an array despite the Eloquent [toArray(..)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-toarray) method. It returns an array of the `stdClass` objects:

```
$sub = MyModel::where([
                    ['my_model.created_at', '>=', $startDate],
                    ['my_model.created_at', '<', $endDate]
                ]);

                $data = DB::table( DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub") )
                ->mergeBindings($sub->getQuery())
                ->selectRaw('SUM(sub.amount) as amount_total')
                ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) as count')
                ->selectRaw(sub.currency_id, sub.site_id, sub.status')
                ->groupByRaw('sub.site_id, sub.currency_id, sub.status')
                ->get()
                ->toArray();
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1282 (8) {
    ["amount_total"]=>
    string(9) "420752.73"
    ["count"]=>
    int(178)
    ["currency_id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["site_id"]=>
    int(1)    
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#1279 (8) {
    ["amount_total"]=>
    string(8) "50448.06"
    ["count"]=>
    int(2)
    ["currency_id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["site_id"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#1277 (8) {
    ["amount_total"]=>
    string(9) "167078.44"
    ["count"]=>
    int(76)
    ["currency_id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["site_id"]=>
    int(1)
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->toArray()` only changes it from `Laravel collection` to `array`. It doesn't affect elements of given collection.

If you want to cast elements to array you can do:

```
->get()
->map(function($item) {
    return (array)$item;
})
->toArray();
```

This will also make every element into `associative array` instead of `object`.

Comment: That makes sense. Believe me I need it, I know how to get an object property value :)
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Please remove the last part, I'll mark it as an answer to my question :)